# Что означает слово "княвать"?

Tags: значение-слов

Что означает слово "княвать"? Какой язык, арго?

Answer (score 4):

Язык - русский. Возможно, диалектизм.

Значение - разглагольствовать, трепаться, вякать.

Сниженная лексика.

Смотрим [в контексте](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rDTuR93jQw0J:loveread.ec/read_book.php%3Fid%3D17425%26p%3D25%20&cd=2&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru):

> После председателя совета отряда («Должность-то какая, – подумал
>   Жиган, – совсем как у пионеров») выступил поп. Он ***долго и нудно
>   княвал что-то о высоких материях*** – воспитательном процессе в
>   колонии, подходе Коммунистической партии к исправлению оступившихся,
>   особой роли труда как средства целебного воздействия на душу
>   заключенных и прочее в том же духе...

В других текстах нашла добавочное значение: княвать - жаловаться, м. б. ябедничать, доносить.

[– ***Не вздумай никому княвать***. Особенно своим друзьям-полицейским. Если хоть один там нарисуется, твоим мамаше и братцу не жить.](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hRlaHWD8cGsJ:loveread.ec/read_book.php%3Fid%3D27004%26p%3D36%20&cd=15&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)

[Или](http://mirror1.ru.indbooks.in/?p=254762):

> – Да они ж как дети малые, – неожиданно стал оправдываться
>   запрудненский авторитет. – Нажрутся, весь город на уши поставят. Так
>   уже было… А мне потом с ментовьем поганым рамсы разводить. Не могу я с
>   ними гужевать. Просекаешь? Не положено.
>
> – Кем не положено?
>
> – А… – Он снова потянулся к графину, но в этот момент мобильный
>   телефон в нагрудном кармане рубашки издал мелодичную трель.
>
> Порожняк вполголоса матернулся, вытащил мобильник, приложил к уху.
>
> – Ну? Че? Тля, я вам что, нянька? Ладно, ***кончай княвать***. Щас буду.

---

[Оговаривать?](http://m.diary.ru/~justforus/p196761903.htm?from=60)

> Есть сволочи в любой профессии, безусловно. Есть те, кто без
>   волшебного пенделя не работают. Но ***княвать на всех поголовно*** - это,
>   извините, не от большого ума, видимо.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что слово не находится в словарях, а в Сети  широко используется.

У меня есть словарь ненормативной лексики (составитель Квеселевич), 2002 год, 15000 слов), но там "княвать" нет.

Comment: А не тот словарь смотрите. Квеселевич вообще не шибко авторитетный автор. Вообще книги с заглавием "Свмый полный словарь...", да еще с предисловием  типа "впервые в истории созданный " - не самый лучший источник достоверных сведений. Впрочем, слова и в других словарях не находится (у Елистратова, У Жиганца и проч.) Но я попробую отыскать Кучинского... И еще был один словарь, Четырехтомник... как его звали-то... Концевич, что ли. Видел я это слово, точно видел.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это воровское (сиречь уголовное) арго.

Не могу найти словарь, где это слово видел зафиксированным в форме "княва" - болтун, трепло. Возможно это был бумажный словарь уголовной лексики Кучинского, его нет в сети, а у меня пропал куда-то.
Поэтому вынужден просить принять на веру.

Разумеется, это не исключает, что слово вырвалось из уголовной среды в большой мир.

Comment: Восторг и уважение! 
Собственно я так и подозревал, потому и вопрос так поставил)) Но! Всё равно! Всем СПАСИБО!! Особенно г-ну бехемотхусу :)

Comment: P.S. Естественно Вы правы, - "княва" -  это уголовное арго - болтун. Также как "кнокать" - писать, сообщать.